# Showing bibtex article entry "number" with revtex

Tags: bibtex, revtex

I am using `revtex4-1` and BibTeX to create a bibliography. Most entries in my bib file shows up fine, but I am having troubles with two journals, Cosmology and astroparticle physics and Living Reviews in relativity that uses the BibTeX entry "number".

For instance in my bib file if I write in a reference of type article:

```
number={4}
```

This entry is ignored in the bibliography so the information about the number does not get included. For "Living Reviews in Relativity" I can cheat and write an entry:

```
pages ={4}
```

instead and make the final bibliography look fine since I do not have to use the pages field for anything else. When I use the bibliographystyle "plainnat", "number" entry shows but not when I use the default `revtex` bibliographystyle. Is there some way of getting the "number" entry to show when using the default `revtex` bibliography style or should I not bother with this and send the article in to the journal and let the editors fix it or complain?

Comment: You shouldn't bother.  Use the `hyperref` package and be sure to include the DOI for each article.  Then it can be disambiguated easily and the editor can format the bibliography to his liking.